# Excel Values Require Enter within Cell to recognize as number

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I have a worksheet where I am getting direct output from STATA that has a weird character format that included " =[ number ]". I put in a new column to strip the characters and leave the numbers. However, the new cell is not recognized as a number, even thought the formatting is turned on to currency. I have to manually click in the cell and then hit `enter` to get it to recognize as a number.

```
A            B                        C
="[-7.734    =RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)     -7.734
```

But When I go to plot values in Col C, it is not working.

A) Why is this happening?
B) Is there a fix for all cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try wrapping your text-trimming formula in `VALUE(...)` to convert the string result to a number.

For example:

```
=VALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-3))
```

Comment: Ah--so simple, but so perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Some more alternatives:

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)+0

=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)*1

=--RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-3)

=SUM(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-3))
```

---

### EDIT

Just to add a bit of explanation...

All of these things work in a similar way.
As standard, the RIGHT function will return as a text string.
However, if possible, Excel will implicitly convert a text string to a number in order to perform a mathematical operation on it. 
Therefore, the problem is solved if we perform a mathematical operation which will not change the result.

As shown, this can be done in a number of ways:

```
Adding zero.
Multiplying by one.
Changing to a negative value and back again.
Summing the single value.
```

Comment: This is a good answer; it would be even better with just a couple of quick words explaining how each possibility works to functionally convert the data to a numeric value.

Comment: @AlexM Fair comment. I was a bit rushed when I wrote this. I will add some explanation when I have time.

Comment: It's pretty much implicit, and I upvoted anyway, I just personally tend to prefer verbose answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do that by "Text to Column" conversion.

1. Select the column and click Data > Text to Column
2. Select Delimiter and then Next
3. Uncheck all the delimiter patterns and click Finish.